# Select changed records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have what I would have thought was a common problem but I have searched and cannot find an answer.

I have a large table containing (simplified) Month, Project, Type, Value

```
Jan ProjectA X 15000,
Jan ProjectB X 2000,
Jan ProjectB Y 2000,
Jan ProjectC X 3000,
.....
Feb ProjectA X 15000,
Feb ProjectB Y  4000,
Feb ProjectC X  3000,
Feb ProjectD X  8989,
.....
Mar ProjectA X 15000,
Mar ProjectB Y  4000,
Mar ProjectC X  3000,
Mar ProjectD X  8989,
.....
```

I need a query which shows:

All projects+type  in Jan but not Feb AND
All projects+type  in Feb but not Jan AND
All projects+type in both but with different Values

I need it between any two months sorry for not being clear

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I have tried sub queries with NOT IN and joins but I feel that I am missing something simple as my queries became very large and still did not work)

Comment: is this a single query `All projects+type in Jan but not Feb AND
All projects+type in Feb but not Jan AND
All projects+type in both but with different Values`?

Comment: While, they are not working, it would be helpful to see a failed attempt at the sql.

Comment: I had meant it as a single query. I will post my attempts next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with aggregation:

```
select project, type,
       (case when sum(case when month = 'jan' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when month = 'feb' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then 'Jan-Only'
             when sum(case when month = 'jan' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
                  sum(case when month = 'feb' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Feb-Only'
             when max(case when month = 'jan' then value else 0 end) <> 
                  max(case when month = 'feb' then value else 0 end)
             then 'Different'
        end) as Which
from largetable lt
group by project, type;
```

Probably the easiest way to filter out the ones where the values are equal in jan and feb is to use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select project, type,
             (case when sum(case when month = 'jan' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                        sum(case when month = 'feb' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                   then 'Jan-Only'
                   when sum(case when month = 'jan' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
                        sum(case when month = 'feb' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                   then 'Feb-Only'
                   when max(case when month = 'jan' then value else 0 end) <> 
                        max(case when month = 'feb' then value else 0 end)
                   then 'Different'
              end) as Which
      from largetable lt
      where month in ('jan', 'feb')
      group by project, type
     ) t
where Which is not null;
```

Comment: The simple solution I was hoping was out there - though I would never have found it - thank you - it works wonderfully